/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./initial)
I am trying to cross compile a hello world code from my ubuntu 22.04 machine to beaglebone black running beaglebone's official release debian AM335x 11.7 2023-09-02 4GB microSD IoT image.
when I compiled on my machine it compiles it with GLIBC 2.36 but beaglebone's particular OS works with 2.31 and when I try to upgrade it says no newer version(Maybe there is no armhf build idk)
finally I was able to run it by statically compiling my program but file size will be larger in the future. Also on my recent diggings I also learned statically building is not so much preffered. How can I run it with non statical way? Thank you.

You need to compile it against GLIBC version you plan to run it with, or against an older version (but not against a newer one). Try downgrading your cross-compilation environment. Static linking with GLIBC is not recommended because it doesn't really do what nost people expect it to do.

if there is no way it is really sad to not have support of it. And I guess there is no easy way to downgrade glibc in my current machine either as I studied. thanks for comment though...

if there is no way there is a way, you have to compile against older glibc version. way to downgrade glibc in my current machine which is why docker is popular, because it is easy in docker to change every library. Either way, for crosscompiling you should have separate host-agnostic environment anyway. And note, if you are compiling on x86 for arm, your host glibc is irrelevant.
